# Hosting WCF service in IIS results in an error

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis

When I try to host my WCF service in IIS, I got this error:

> The DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest method is not supported in the integrated IIS pipeline mode.

How to fix this? Didn't find the solution in google.. (Or I have not searched well enough)

Comment: Change the application pool's managed pipeline mode to the Classic and try.If not try to reset IIS.

Comment: Now I receive this error: Can't load on of the files from assembly System.Web, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a. The system can not find the specified file.

Comment: Its an indication that you are missing the assembly.Does your solution has that assembly if yes where is it fetched from(path)?

Comment: This is my pad: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HelloAcmeService where the Service is stored. This is the pad that I type in to go to my service: http://localhost/HelloAcmeService/AcmeService.svc (in browser) And this where my assembly is been saved in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HelloAcmeService/bin/HelloAcmeService.dll

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific:

I made in Visual Studio a new solution: With 2 projects:

1) HelloAcmeClient

2) HelloAcmeService

This solution is stored in: D:\robbe\Documents\Visual Basic\repos\HelloAcmeService

For my IIS, everything is stored in: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HelloAcmeService
My map looks there like
[The IIS-map where I store everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvLmu.png)

I know this is working because, I tested it with a stuff.html file.

Comment: You should edit your question and include this information with it. This is not an answer.